# Can't extract string from database sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My aim is to test if the user and password inserted, existed in Table1.
However, if I typed (pink,floyd) which exists in the database count still null and it appears the message "user doesn't exist".

```
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String user=f_user.getText().trim();
                String pass=f_pass.getText().trim();
                String sql="select   user, pass from \"Table1\" where user='"+user+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
                rs=stat.executeQuery(sql);
                int count=0;
                while(rs.next()){
                    count++;
                }
                if (count==0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user doesn't exist");
                else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "acces permitted");
            } catch ( Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            
        }
```

Here's my database :

[image]

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use DB_login that contains the table above. I'm working with postgresql  , pgAdmin 3 program

Comment: Where do you initialise your `Statement` object `stat`? Is it possible you have it open for an another query at the same time? Also, your `ResultSet` `rs` seems to have too wide a scope. Please scope these variables local to the method you use them in.

Comment: probably you need to trim you columns, like `select * from table1 where trim("user") = '...`

Comment: If i do this , I will destroy the hole code.But I tried to extract Table1 and I successed .So the problem is with the line of sql ,it didn't return any row.

Comment: @Lashane, this would be true in e.g. Oracle, but Postgresql should handle `VARCHAR` <> `CHARACTER` comparisons transparently without trimming (even though `CHARACTER` data is stored blank-padded), according to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html).

Comment: @ghassen92, what would destroy your code? Limiting the scope of `Resultset` to a minimum is something you _have to_ do if you want to avoid hard-to-trace bugs.

Comment: @Lashane , your solution work for me i changed Sql to 
 String sql="select   * from \"Table1\" where trim(\"user\")= '"+user+"' and trim(\"pass\")= '"+pass+"'";

Comment: @MickMnemonic , what i wrote is just a piece of long class ,If i changed  the variable to local ,  I have to do some changing in the others methods.

Comment: @Lashane it seems that pass and user that I typed weren't the same in Table1   cuz they hadn't the same length

Comment: @ghassen92, looks like I misinterpreted Postgresql documentation and `CHARACTER` to `VARCHAR` comparisons don't work without trimming, after all. A better long term solution would be to switch to using `VARCHAR` data type in your table descriptions; otherwise you need to always remember to add trimming for queries that come from JDBC. If you change one of your `ResultSet`s into a local variable with a different name, you don't have to change other parts of your code. But you really should do this for all methods using the variable to avoid problems with e.g. slow queries that can overlap.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but it looks like you have some SQL injection going on in your code. String concatenation for a piece of SQL is in many cases the start of security problems. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns that the stocked user and pass parameters in Table1 hasn't the same length of input parameters . So , we need to change :

```
String sql="select   user, pass from \"Table1\" where user='"+user+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
```

to

```
String sql="select * from \"Table1\" where trim(\"user\")= '"+user+"' and trim(\"pass\")= '"+pass+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem you had - cos you updated was that your sql was invalid. you're missing FROM.

Comment: it wasn't when i commented. he updated it and now he updated his entire question :)

Comment: sorry for the confusion :P

Answer (score 0):

You had created table1 but sql is from table2.